# How to change inline onClick function of radio button to a separate script

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, google-chrome-extension

I want to change the inline js function to a normal JS script for Chrome Extention.

example code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Select your favorite browser:</p>
<form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer<br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value="Firefox">Firefox<br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value="Opera">Opera<br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value="Google Chrome">Google Chrome<br>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" value="Safari">Safari<br><br>

    Your favorite browser is: <input type="text" id="result">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction(browser) {
    document.getElementById("result").value = browser;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what I tried but it's not working as expected

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Select your favorite browser:</p>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="radio" name="browser"  value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer<br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser"  value="Firefox">Firefox<br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser"  value="Opera">Opera<br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser"  value="Google Chrome">Google Chrome<br>
  <input type="radio" name="browser"  value="Safari">Safari<br><br>

  Your favorite browser is: <input type="text" id="result">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>

<script>
const browsers = document.getElementsByName("browser");
browsers.forEach(function(browser){
  myFunction(browser.value);
});
function myFunction(browser) {
  document.getElementById("result").value = browser;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How to solve is this. I want to change the value onChange/onClick of radioButton .

Comment: So where is addEventListener? You correctly loop over them, you just need to bind the event.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following is very similar to the 1st answer, but I added some testing code for the OP to evaluate for future endeavors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
<title> Test Page </title>
<body>
<!-- Modified from: 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70467382/how-to-change-inline-onclick-function-of-radio-button-to-a-separate-script/704675066
-->
<p>Select your favorite browser:</p>

<!--
    Following replaces: <form action="/action_page.php"> in original
    Following FORM actions are for testing purposes ONLY 
    Replace with correct FORM actions when necessary
-->
<!-- <form action="javascript:alert('success')"> -->
<form action="javascript:submitParameters()">

  <label><input type="radio" name="browser"  value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="browser"  value="Firefox">Firefox</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="browser"  value="Opera">Opera</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="browser"  value="Google Chrome">Google Chrome</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="browser"  value="Safari">Safari</label><br>
  <br>
  Your favorite browser is: <input type="text" id="result">
  <br><input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>

<script>
const browsers = document.getElementsByName("browser");
browsers.forEach(function(browser, ndx) {
  browser.addEventListener('click', function() { myFunction(browser, ndx); });
});
function myFunction(browser, ndx) {
  document.getElementById("result").value = ndx+' : '+browser.value;
}
</script>

<script>
function submitParameters() {  // for FORM submit testing purposes only
  let tmp = document.getElementById('result').value;
  // do nothing messages for results evaluation with a small error check test
  if (tmp !== '') { alert('Selection: '+tmp); } else { alert('Selection is missing'); }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I always wanted to know what was being sent to the FORM on SUBMIT.
I added the 'javascript:alert' to the action to report this.
Same thing is accomplished with the 'javascript:function' shorter format

Passing invalid data is frowned upon and is best avoided.
I added a test in the 'submitParameters()' function to report a missing choice if no radio button is selected.

Sometimes the choice reported to the FORM via the SUBMIT is desired to be an index of the selection, numbered 0-4 in this example.  I added code in the .forEach function that passes the index of the option selected.  Totally unnecessary, but has a possible use in future codes.

Happy coding and Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, you forgot to actually add the `myFunction` function as an event listener. For that, you should take a look at [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Your script would have to be something like this:

```
<script>
const browsers = document.getElementsByName("browser");
browser.forEach(function(browser) {
  browser.addEventListener('click', function() {
    myFunction(browser);
  });
});
function myFunction(browser) {
  document.getElementById("result").value = browser;
}
</script>
```

The reason we have to create an anonymous function around `myFunction` is because we are calling it with a parameter. If we simply passed `myFunction(browser)`, the function would simply be executed and not passed as a callback to the event listener

Answer (score 0):

In your new code you need to add an event listener for each time the radio button is selected.  Your code never calls the routine to change anything.

Comment: You might want to show him how

Comment: Others type faster than me and now the question has been answered.  Gave the same information I would have provided.  Thought OP wanted a hint, not the absolute code.

Comment: I think the OP is not at the level where hinting would make a difference 